# Odd behavior with UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom cell with two labels and a image. I receive some data from internet in Json. Everything works fine; every cell fills with the correspondent data. I've added a new label that has to be filled just like the other ones. This is the data:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendCell") as! friendCell

cell.friendPicture?.image = newImageUser

cell.friendName.text = "@\(theName[indexPath.row])"

if repliesNumber[indexPath.row] == "0"{

        cell.repliesNumber.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else{

        cell.repliesNumber.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"backgroundPattern")!)
    }

if AttachedImage[indexPath.row] != ""{

        cell.backgroundColor = .orangeColor()

    }
```

For testing I've made to be colored the first two cells. My issue is that the fist two cells get colored, but if I scroll down, every two, three, four cells (depending on the device -device height I guess-, another two cells get colored too.

It's odd/weird because the rest of labels work fine.

Where should I start looking?

If I print the json data I receive everything is okay

Here is a gif:

[GIF](http://www.wastring.com/hello.gif)

Basically my problem is that when I scroll down the data disappear but only from a label, the rest of labels and images doesn't.

Comment: Classic cell reuse problem.  Cells are reused after they scroll off the screen, so you need to make sure you set the cell.background color to an appropriate value for all cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or you will see the color from when the cell was used previously.

Comment: I faced similar issue. Below link helped me to solve problem... Can you try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985451/uitableview-cell-colour-changes-on-scrolling-query

Comment: I didn't help me :( It's only with that label

Comment: did you tried cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; ? Try it before getting text. Don't check for nil condition.. it works for me. I had exact problem. Also which method you are writing above code?

Comment: my code is in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: mine too. But it's already solved. Many thanks.

Comment: how did you solved it?

Comment: With the answer below, with the green tick It's more or less wat you were telling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear from your code which are the cells that are "colored". Is it from the orangeColor() condition ?

Anyway, UITableViewCells in an UITableView are reused, which means you are given them in the exact same state you left them. This is why, if you don't reset your backgroundColor, they still are orange as you scroll.

So basically, whenever you do something in a certain condition in a cell, don't forget to restore its state when the condition is not met. In your case, this gives :

```
// cellForRowAtIndexPath {
if itemIsMultimedia() {
    cell.Multimedia.text = "it's multimedia"
    cell.Multimedia.hidden = false
}
else {
    cell.Multimedia.text = ""
    cell.Multimedia.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: I'll try to simplify it. In my custom cell I have 2 items; an image and a textLabel. These two dates are filled okey even scrolling down and scrolling up, the data is there for every indexPath row. I added a third item, a label that says if that cell has multimedia or nor. When I run by first time the tableView, data shows perfectly. But when I scroll down and scroll up when I was before scrolling down, the data disappear. But that's only with that last label I added, the other two items don't disspaear

Comment: Can you edit your question with more code ? Maybe a gif/screenshot of what's wrong ? Because it's still unclear to me.

Comment: Well, it looks like a reuse issue as well, but not related to the colored/orange issue. Is there a place where you set your multimediaLabel to "it's multimedia" then "" and forget to put it back to "it's multimedia" when needed ?

Comment: I've made an answer to my own question for you to see where I do that.

Comment: But that's what I make in the previous code, isn't it? I check if it's multimedia so I update the label. Else I hide it.

Comment: No, it is not exactly what you do. It is because a cell is reused that you need to tell the cell.Multimedia to hide or not. If you don't, you will hide the cell and whenever it's get reused, you will be given a cell with cell.Multimedia already hidden. You will be able to set new text but it will never appear (because you hided it)

Comment: Okay, Now it works. I had to delete the cell.label.hiden and I change it to display another string. Many thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

here @aimak

```
if AttachedImage[indexPath.row] != ""{

        cell.Multimedia.text = "It's multimedia"

    }
    else{

        cell.Multimedia.hidden = true
    }
```

Comment: So what could I do? I check the array, if in the cell position is true the label says "It's multimedia", if not, it hides. Anyways, things like that is what I do with the rest of labels. I don't know why with this one is different.